# how to dismiss changes from onclicklistener on click again in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, onclick, android-linearlayout

i have this clicklistener:

```
holder.linearLayout_soul_bg.setOnClickListener {

            setBackgroundColor(R.color.soul_bg)
            holder.inspirationtext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.like.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cancle_soul))
            holder.inspiration_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.sourcetext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.sharetext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.sharetext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_share_bg_white)
        }
```

that makes changes on the design if the user click on it

how can i undo these changes if the user click again?

Comment: I think you should do it manually. I haven't seen any methods for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used isSelected as follow:

```
holder.linearLayout_soul_bg.setOnClickListener {


            it.isSelected = !it.isSelected
            if (it.isSelected) {
                //do whatever here if true
            } else {
                //do whatever here if false

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a `Boolean` every time button is clicked like

```
private val clicked = false 
holder.linearLayout_soul_bg.setOnClickListener {
    clicked = !clicked
    if( clicked ) {
            setBackgroundColor(R.color.soul_bg)
            holder.inspirationtext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.like.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cancle_soul))
            holder.inspiration_title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.sourcetext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.sharetext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            holder.sharetext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_share_bg_white)
    }
    else{
         // do your work for setting defaults
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Anshul suggested will definitely work, but it looks like you need a view that has a certain state.
Think, maybe it will be more convenient for you to use the checkbox or toggle button.
These views can be styled as you need, I think it will be more logical.

You may use checkbox like this:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    if (isChecked){
        // your logic
    }
}
```